# Developer performance report in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I want to create a TFS report, which, for every iteration would show 2 numbers:

1. number of tasks (active or proposed), assigned to a particular user (me) at the beginning of the iteration and
2. number of completed tasks (resolved or closed), at the end of the iteration.

What is the easiest way to implement such report (so that I can automatically update it on a daily basis) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if it can be accomplished with out-of-the-box TFS installation bc TFS doesn't store changes of the *Assign to* field. More likely u'll need to create such an utility where you can manually analyze TFS data.